# C# call C++ method on a target process

Tags: c#, c++

I injected a small DLL for test purposes to an another process (in this case notepad)

I can pass two string:

C# (host)

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct MessageStruct
    {
        [CustomMarshalAs(CustomUnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string Text;
        [CustomMarshalAs(CustomUnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string Caption;
    }

    public void DoIt()
    {
            MessageStruct data = new MessageStruct() { Text = "Some", Caption = "thing" };
            injector.CallExport("ClassRPG.dll", "InitWithMessage", data);
    }
```

C++ (target process - injected dll)

```
    // header
    DWORD WINAPI DllMain( HMODULE, DWORD_PTR, LPVOID );
    typedef struct _INIT_STRUCT {
        LPCWSTR Title;
        LPCWSTR Message;
    } INIT_STRUCT, *PINIT_STRUCT;
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void InitWithMessage( PVOID );

    // cpp
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void InitWithMessage( PVOID message ) {
            PINIT_STRUCT messageStruct = reinterpret_cast<PINIT_STRUCT>(message);
            ::MessageBox(NULL, messageStruct->Message, messageStruct->Title, MB_OK);
    }
```

But with a simple int it doesn't work (the target process crash)

C#

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct DataPasser
    {
        public int pointer;
    }

    public void DoIt()
    {
            IntPtr dataPtr = ChangeAndAllocValues();
            DataPasser dp = new DataPasser() { pointer = dataPtr.ToInt32() };
            injector.CallExport("ClassRPG.dll", "GetData", dp);
    }
```

C++ (target process - injected dll)

```
    // header
    DWORD WINAPI DllMain( HMODULE, DWORD_PTR, LPVOID );
    typedef struct _INIT_DATA {
            int pointer;
    } INIT_DATA, *PINIT_DATA;
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetData( PVOID );

    // cpp
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetData( PVOID data )
    {
            PINIT_DATA hnd = reinterpret_cast<PINIT_DATA>(data);
    }
```

I tried almost everything, worked on it for hours but i could not get it to work.

Comment: Try to align your structure memory.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan What do you mean?

Comment: My gut tells me you might be mixing up 32/64bit data models. The model of your calling application, your dll AND the process you're injecting the function in should be the same (and unless 32-bit, cross-language issues might apply).

Comment: @Blindy I checked my app and dll, all of them target x86 architecture.   Plus i changed int to Int64 (c#) and long int (c++) + the pointer to Int64, but the target process is still crashing.

Comment: You're already seeing the problems here, `long int` isn't 64bit. And you didn't mention what model the process you're injecting is using (notepad). Whatever you're injecting is running in its memory space using its rules.